# Maven Eclipse volume label syntax error

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

When I do a clean all on my maven project in Eclipse, it always comes back with the following error:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

I have the maven builder and java bulider enabled. Does anyone know what this error means?

thanks,

Jeff

Comment: That's the entire error? Doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: I know, but that's all I get. The error log has some stack trace info:

Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:396)
at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:559)
at org.codehaus.groovy.maven.plugin.CompilerMojoSupport.addSourceRoot(CompilerMojoSupport.java:80)
at org.codehaus.groovy.maven.plugin.stubgen.AbstractGenerateStubsMojo.addSourceRoot(AbstractGenerateStubsMojo.java:113)
at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be related to bug [MECLIPSE-269](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-issues/200904.mbox/%3C29913841.15691240267425013.JavaMail.haus-jira@codehaus01.managed.contegix.com%3E): the full error message might help as this  "
"`java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`" is actually the root cause of "`org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Can't canonicalize system path`".

> I get a "`Can't canonicalize system path`" error using the goal `eclispse:eclipse` when
>   the `<warSourceDirectory>` of the maven-war-plugin starts with `${basedir}`.
>   If I remove the `${basedir}`, the build is successful. 
>   If, as it appears, the war plugin uses different rules related to the prefixing a path
>   with ${basedir}, then I consider it a bug because the configuration of `<warSourceDirectory>` is inconsistent with similar tags.

Comment: yeah, i think that solved this problem. I'm still having some other groovy maven plugins, but thanks for this help.

Comment: @Jeff: you are welcome. You can also post a more detailed feedback about what you had to change/update in order to get rid of that specific issue.

Comment: I think I had some version mismatches. I cleared out my entire local repository and updated to all of the latest groovy libraries and gmaven libraries, and all seems to be working now. Thanks again.

Comment: @VonC I'm seeing the same error output when I try to install mvn. I'm trying to set up an eclipse project on win7. I've looked through some of the Jira issues, but I'm uncertain what I need to change in my POM file (if thats the real issue). Any thoughts?

Comment: @Dan No thought except about trying the latest version (of Eclipse, of the mvn plugin, ...), and post a new question if the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

use the following command to get exact cause of an error.

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -X
```

The result of above command will help you to fix an issue.